# How to pass parameters on redirecting using Vue Router

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have a sample Vue router here which handles going to the login first before accessing the form with a specific id:

```
router = new VueRouter({
             routes: [
                 {path: '/form/:id', redirect: '/login'},
                 {path: '/login', name: 'Login', component: Login}
             ]
         });
```

Is there a way that the login can still access the :id parameter passed since when I run http://localhost:8080/form/c101-101 it directly redirects to the Login component and when I try to log this.$route.params.id inside the login component it's **undefined**. Is there a way I can pass the :id on redirect?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make /:id as optional in login routes as follows:-

```
router = new VueRouter({
         routes: [
             {path: '/form/:id', redirect: '/login/:id'},
             {path: '/login/:id?', name: 'Login', component: Login}
         ]
     });
```

With above snippet of code you will get this.$route.params.id in login component.

Comment: One caveat about this approach: if one needs to keep both `/feature` and `/feature/:id` as separate routes (which is an often used pattern for list and edit pages), using `/feature/:id?` would supersede `/feature`, so it wouldn't be an applicable solution in this scenario.

Comment: This does not work anymore in 2023/24

Comment: Yeah I think the workaround would be to use pass a function as render (dynamic routing) see https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/redirect-and-alias.html#Redirect

Answer (score 22):

You can use a function for dynamic redirecting, [as per the Vue docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/redirect-and-alias.html#redirect).

Here's an example taking a param (e.g. `yourdomain.com/:yourParam`) and redirecting to another URL, using the param (`yourParam`) as a query string (`yourdomain.com/your/route?yourQueryString=:yourParam`):

```
redirect: to => ({
  name: "your-named-route",
  query: { yourQueryString: to.params.yourParam },
}),
```

*note: this syntax is using ES6.*

Comment: how to use it into a function when a click has been fired?

Comment: Instead of forwarding the parameter as a query parameter (and I don't see that the OP asked for that) you can use redirect: to => ({
  path: '/form/' + to.params.id
}),